# How to make python3 aware of manually compiled opencv?

Tags: raspbian, python-3, opencv

all this is on a 4Gb RPi 4GB. I compiled opencv from source following this [guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-opencv/comment-page-1/?unapproved=33785&moderation-hash=d9719ecaa56d9f35d359dbbe6a0ab4ea#comment-33785) and it built and compiled ok. Running `opencv_version` reports `4.4.0-dev`. But in python3 when running import cv2 it says:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I followed virtually the same (some parts I felt were copypasted verbatim) guide from different source to compile opencv inside a ubuntu 20 vm and that worked without a hitch, but I wanted to put opencv on one of the less used rpi's of mine.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706218/how-to-add-my-local-compiled-opencv-to-python-path?

Comment: @Swedgin - yes and no, it got me further but it still errors out. I did `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/pi/opencv/build/python_loader` to inform python of the install (although this was not necessary on ubuntu), now it starts the import but cancels with `ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config-3.7.py', 'config-3.py']. Check OpenCV installation.` I've ran the `sudo make install` again and it confirms all files are in right place and up to date. I've no idea where they ought to be or what's supposed to be in them.what to even put in them

Comment: I'm sorry, can't help you further. Googling that importerror gives lots of hits but I'm not sure which one could help you.